# How to add a stroke to ShapeDrawable

Tags: android, drawable

Hi
I want to create a shape drawable and fill it with gradient color with white stroke
here is my code

```
    ShapeDrawable greenShape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    Shader shader1 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 50, new int[] {
            0xFFBAF706, 0xFF4CD52F  }, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    greenShape.getPaint().setShader(shader1);
    greenShape.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(3);
    greenShape.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    greenShape.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);`
```

The problem is the rectangle appears with gradient fill but without stroke

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in code.  Is it something you could do in xml?

Comment: It's so easy with xml, but in my case, I want to do it with java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this person struggled with the same issue and the only way they found was to subclass the ShapeDrawable:

[Trying to draw a button: how to set a stroke color and how to "align" a gradient to the bottom without knowing the height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145131/trying-to-draw-a-button-how-to-set-a-stroke-color-and-how-to-align-a-gradient)

Comment: I think it's a bug on Android SDK

Answer (score 14):

The `ShapeDrawable` does not allow you to easily draw a stroke around it.
If you really want then [this](http://betaful.com/post/82668809883/programmatic-shapes-in-android) would be a nice place to look at.

OR

You could use a GradientDrawable

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(Color.RED);
gd.setCornerRadius(10);
gd.setStroke(2, Color.WHITE);
```

(PS: This is given as a comment in the same page!)

Comment: How do I make it OvalShape? Meaning a filled circle, with a stroke of another color?

Answer (score 1):

```
<stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#808080" />
```

try it, it will work definitely

Answer (score 0):

Change the style to greenShape.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)
and

```
greenShape.setShaderFactory(new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            return new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```