# Set android shape color programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

I am editing to make the question simpler, hoping that helps towards an accurate answer.

Say I have the following `oval` shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:angle="270"
           android:color="#FFFF0000"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#FFAA0055"/>
</shape>
```

How do I set the color programmatically, from within an activity class?

Comment: What do you set this drawable to?

Comment: The drawable is an `oval` and is the background of an ImageView.

Comment: If this question as asked is too difficult, is there a way to draw multiple images onto a canvas and set the layered end product as the background of a view?

Comment: You can achieve this by extending the `View` class, and using it as the `base` view in a layout that allows overlapping of widgets(`RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout`). Inside this extended `View` class, you can `draw multiple images onto a canvas`. But, before doing that, take a look at this --> [Link](http://www.betaful.com/2012/01/programmatic-shapes-in-android/) (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 312):

***Note***: Answer has been updated to cover the scenario where `background` is an instance of `ColorDrawable`. Thanks [Tyler Pfaff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629259/tyler-pfaff), for pointing this out.

> The drawable is an oval and is the background of an ImageView

Get the `Drawable` from `imageView` using `getBackground()`:

```
Drawable background = imageView.getBackground();
```

Check against usual suspects:

```
if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
    // cast to 'ShapeDrawable'
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) background;
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
    // cast to 'GradientDrawable'
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) background;
    gradientDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    // alpha value may need to be set again after this call
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) background;
    colorDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
}
```

Compact version:

```
Drawable background = imageView.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
    ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
    ((GradientDrawable)background).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    ((ColorDrawable)background).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
}
```

Note that null-checking is not required.

However, you should use `mutate()` on the drawables before modifying them if they are used elsewhere. (By default, drawables loaded from XML share the same state.)

Comment: Thanks for answering. (+1). My code is experiencing other bugs so it's difficult to test. But still this might set the `solid` portion of the shape. How about the `stroke` portion?

Comment: @TiGer You should add `@username` in your comment to make sure a notification is sent to the user. By the way, you will need to subclass `ShapeDrawable` in order to set the stroke portion. More info here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3663956). Look at the comment as it mentions a problem with the accepted answer.

Comment: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable

The cast fails on me

Comment: @John If your `ImageView's` background is set to a `GradientDrawable`, `getBackground()` will not return a `ShapeDrawable`. Instead, use the `GradientDrawable` that is returned: `GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable)imageView.getBackground();`.... `gradientDrawable.setColors(new int[] { color1, color2 });`.

Comment: @Vikram could you help with a similar question here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398658/change-the-shape-color-of-a-imagebutton

Comment: @vikram what if it's a ColorDrawable?

Comment: @TylerPfaff I have updated the answer to cover the case of `ColorDrawable`. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks @Vikram. I'm getting some really really weird side effects from this method. Random other views in my app are taking on the colors of different views that have had their background set with this method. getPaint() looks suspicious to me in the ShapeDrawable case. Is anyone else having this problem? Perhaps setting the paint color affects more than just the object you are currently working with?

Comment: @Vikram I figured out my issue described above. You must call mutate() to avoid coloring any view that shares a drawable with the one you are coloring. :)

Comment: Can someone explain me why the explicit casts?

Comment: @joaquin `getPaint()` is only accessible on a `ShapeDrawable`, not `Drawable` - hence the explicit cast. `setColor(int)` is not available for `Drawable` or any common parent of `GradientDrawable` & `ColorDrawable` - hence the explicit casts.

Comment: "However, you should use mutate() on the drawables before modifying them if they are used elsewhere. (By default, drawables loaded from XML share the same state.)" Any ideas how can I use mutate() if that is the case? Thanks!

Comment: Very thorough and helpful answer! I would never have guessed my `<shape>` resource was actually a GradientDrawable instead of a ShapeDrawable. Your laying out the options and how to tell which it was saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I found that even though my background drawable was a <Shape> in the XML, I got both GradientDrawable and ColorDrawable back in the code.  So had to handle all of them as in the example.

Answer (score 79):

A simpler solution nowadays would be to use your shape as a background and then programmatically change its color via:

```
view.background.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#343434"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

See [PorterDuff.Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode#enum-values_1) for the available options.

**UPDATE (API 29):**

The above method is deprecated since API 29 and replaced by the following:

```
view.background.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#343434"), BlendMode.SRC_ATOP)
```

See [BlendMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlendMode) for the available options.

Comment: Correct one is:   `view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#343434"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` Since there may be a border on the background or rounded courners.

Comment: Nice one @BerkayTurancı my shape did have rounded corners. I could omit the `getBackground()` call. My imageview.src contained a shape and I used: `imageIndicator.setColorFilter(toggleColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` where `toggleColor` is just an int that previously stored the result from getColor()

Comment: Having `PorterDuff.Mode` for `BlendModeColorFilter` won't compile as it requires `BlendMode`. So for API 29 it should be `view.background.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#343434"), BlendMode.SRC_ATOP)`.

Comment: Good catch @Onik. I've updated the answer accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: @Onik but BlendMode.SRC_ATOP does not preserve stroke !

Answer (score 51):

Do like this:

```
    ImageView imgIcon = findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
    GradientDrawable backgroundGradient = (GradientDrawable)imgIcon.getBackground();
    backgroundGradient.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
```

Comment: @user3111850 Did you add `android:background` in your xml or even `setBackground`in activity before you call `getBackground()` ? It should works if you had done so.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 26):

This question was answered a while back, but it can modernized by rewriting as a kotlin extension function.

```
fun Drawable.overrideColor(@ColorInt colorInt: Int) {
    when (this) {
        is GradientDrawable -> setColor(colorInt)
        is ShapeDrawable -> paint.color = colorInt
        is ColorDrawable -> color = colorInt
    }
}
```

Comment: Rly nice answer! Thnx you!

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
 public void setGradientColors(int bottomColor, int topColor) {
 GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]  
 {bottomColor, topColor});
 gradient.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
 gradient.setCornerRadius(10.f);
 this.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
 }
```

for more detail check this link [this](http://bnotions.com/efficient-use-of-drawables-to-develop-a-dynamic-ui-on-android/)

hope help.

Comment: up vote for the link. But it's not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 15):

hope this will help someone with the same issue

```
GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) YourImageView.getBackground();
//To shange the solid color
gd.setColor(yourColor)

//To change the stroke color
int width_px = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, youStrokeWidth, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
gd.setStroke(width_px, yourColor);
```

Comment: Initially I couldn't get this to work, I figured out **yourColor** must be provided like this: `gd.setStroke(width_px, Color.parseColor("#FF5722"));`

Answer (score 12):

Expanding on [Vikram's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558882/vikram) answer, if you are coloring dynamic views, like recycler view items, etc.... Then you probably want to call mutate() before you set the color. If you don't do this, any views that have a common drawable (i.e a background) will also have their drawable changed/colored.

```
public static void setBackgroundColorAndRetainShape(final int color, final Drawable background) {

    if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
        ((ShapeDrawable) background.mutate()).getPaint().setColor(color);
    } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
        ((GradientDrawable) background.mutate()).setColor(color);
    } else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        ((ColorDrawable) background.mutate()).setColor(color);
    }else{
        Log.w(TAG,"Not a valid background type");
    }

}
```

Comment: needs and extra check and parameter:        `if (background instanceof LayerDrawable) {
            background = ((LayerDrawable) background.mutate()).getDrawable(indexIfLayerDrawable);
        } if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable)[...]` to deal with backgrounds layouts that use `<layer-list ... <item ...`.

Answer (score 7):

this is the solution that works for me...wrote it in another question as well:
[How to change shape color dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically)

```
//get the image button by id
ImageButton myImg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.some_id);

//get drawable from image button
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) myImg.getDrawable();

//set color as integer
//can use Color.parseColor(color) if color is a string
drawable.setColor(color)
```

Answer (score 7):

Nothing work for me but when i set tint color it works on Shape Drawable

```
 Drawable background = imageView.getBackground();
 background.setTint(getRandomColor())
```

require android 5.0 API 21

Comment: Elegant solution. Simple and works flawlessly.

Comment: Nice and short solution !

Answer (score 3):

My ***Kotlin*** extension function version based on answers above with ***Compat***:

```
fun Drawable.overrideColor_Ext(context: Context, colorInt: Int) {
    val muted = this.mutate()
    when (muted) {
        is GradientDrawable -> muted.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorInt))
        is ShapeDrawable -> muted.paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorInt))
        is ColorDrawable -> muted.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorInt))
        else -> Log.d("Tag", "Not a valid background type")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to fill the shape with the **Radius** is:

```
(view.getBackground()).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFDE03"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using C# Xamarin, here is a method based on Vikram's snippet:

```
private void SetDrawableColor(Drawable drawable, Android.Graphics.Color color)
{
    switch (drawable)
    {
        case ShapeDrawable sd:
            sd.Paint.Color = color;
            break;
        case GradientDrawable gd:
            gd.SetColor(color);
            break;
        case ColorDrawable cd:
            cd.Color = color;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I am too late.But if you are using Kotlin. There is way like this

```
var gd = layoutMain.background as GradientDrawable

 //gd.setCornerRadius(10)
  gd.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx , R.color.lightblue))
  gd.setStroke(1, ContextCompat.getColor(ctx , R.color.colorPrimary)) // (Strokewidth,colorId)
```

Enjoy....

Answer (score 1):

This might help

1.Set the shape color initially to transparent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
   <solid android:angle="270"
       android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
   <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FFAA0055"/>
</shape>
```

2. Set the shape as a background to the view
3. Set your preferred color as follows:

   ```
   Drawable bg = view.getBackground();
   bg.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#Color"), PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this in my adapter but the solutions above were either not working or required >= android version 10. The code below worked for me!

```
val drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(holder.courseName.background)
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.parseColor("#4a1f60"))
```

**EDIT!!:** OR if your color is an Int and not a Hex

```
val myDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(holder.courseName.background)
DrawableCompat.setTint(myDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context, newColor))
```

**ADDED INFO!!:** Another way to do this is to get the drawable, change its tint first, then set it to the background of your view.

```
val tintDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_shape)!!.mutate()
DrawableCompat.setTint(tintDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context, newColor))
view.background = tintDrawable
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to change Solid color of custom drawable is
For Kotlin.

```
 (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.testing1).getBackground()).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFDE03"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create this kotlin function.

```
fun View.updateViewBGSolidColor(colorString: String) {
    when (val background: Drawable = this.background) {
        is ShapeDrawable -> {
            background.paint.color = Color.parseColor(colorString)
        }
        is GradientDrawable -> {
            background.setColor(Color.parseColor(colorString))
        }
        is ColorDrawable -> {
            background.color = Color.parseColor(colorString)
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like the below:

```
yourTextView.updateViewBGSolidColor("#FFFFFF")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
        new int[] {0xFF616261,0xFF131313});
gd.setCornerRadius(0f);

layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2023 with compileSdkVersion 33 the [most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825210/9198523) at this moment worked in some way. My shape it's a simple rounded border for a complex view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

The shape is set as `background` in a view with name `VScroll`. I need the color of the shape to be the same as the themed view so I adapted the accepted answer and set the color in the `Fragment`:

```
val lineBackground = binding.vScroll.background as GradientDrawable
lineBackground.setStroke(5,Color.parseColor(line.color))
```

Where `line.color` is an hexadecimal string value like `#FFFFFF`. The int value for the `stroke width` is set in pixels, so it has to be converted to `dp` for a correct size.