# How to modify color of a drawable programatically

Tags: android, android-drawable

Hi I have a shape drawable in xml and it is used as background of a view. Its color needs to be changed in the code depending on conditions.

So I am doing

```
  ShapeDrawable d =  (ShapeDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape1);

  d.getPaint().setShader(sd1);
```

but the getDrawable returns a gradient  drawable, casting it to ShapeDrawable generates error.

So how can I get shapeDrawable in code and modify its attributes.

Comment: Set the `drawable` to an `ImageView` first. Following that, this would work - `(ShapeDrawable)imageView.getBackground();`. For more info, look at this answer: [Set android shape color programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17825210/2558882)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by casting as a GradientDrawable instead of ShapeDrawable.

```
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape1);

    shape.setColor(Color);
```

I used this when I created an activity with a custom style based on the Holo.Dialog theme.

Comment: Thanks - if you change the color of a Drawable, does it change it **everywhere it is used** ?!

Comment: @Fattie No it won't.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet worked for me:

```
PorterDuffColorFilter porterDuffColorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

imgView.getDrawable().setColorFilter(porterDuffColorFilter);
imgView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set the color:

```
d.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a generic function in which you can pass context, icon is id drawable/mipmap image icon and new color which you need for that icon.

This function returns a drawable.

```
public static Drawable changeDrawableColor(Context context,int icon, int newColor) {
    Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, icon).mutate(); 
    mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)); 
    return mDrawable;
} 

changeDrawableColor(getContext(),R.mipmap.ic_action_tune, Color.WHITE);
```