# android change button stroke color

Tags: android, button, drawable

I have a button that on start has a white border. This is set in the button def by applying a xml background using the following:

```
android:background="@drawable/butt1"
```

The butt1 def is as follows:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
android:topRightRadius="30dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
/>

<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>

<stroke
android:width="4dp"
android:color="#FFFFFF"
/>
</shape>
```

This works fine as long as I have a dark background for the activity

My app can change backgrounds and when I change to a light background  I cant see the button because of the stroke color being white (#FFFFFF)

How do I change the color of the border to say black(#000000) if the background is changed to white

I can change the text color to black using

```
Button view5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sett);  
view5.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

but cant work out how to apply a new xml background style

Any help appreciated

mark

Comment: U need to write 2 xml for the same and can switch aoorcordingly in activity

Comment: See this answer: [Set android shape color programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17825210/2558882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second `butt1` xml for **black border** and when the background color change to light then you can call `view5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.butt1_black_border);` to change the background of the button using the xml with black border

EDIT:

`view5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.butt1_black_border);`

Comment: Thanks for this but when i set it i get an error "The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (Drawable)"

Answer (score 1):

> How do I change the color of the border to say black(#000000)

Alter view's drawable:

```
Button view5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sett); 
ShapeDrawable gradientDrawable = (ShapeDrawable)view5.getBackground(); 
gradientDrawable.setStroke(2, color);
```

See [setStroke() docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setStroke(int,%20int)).

Comment: true, true. Corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use on focus change listener & set background drawable.There will be two drawable with different stroke color by checking boolean value set button background -

```
view5.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```