# Programmatically assign color to shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/user_color">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="25dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/user_background" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How I'm calling the shape:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">
```

How can I programmatically change the color of the rectangle shape with id `user_color`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set android shape color programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @user5262809
         // add id to your linear layout

        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">

        // then in code do this :
        LinearLayout linearView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        // added Anitha's code here
    int colorToPaint = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white);// any color you want
    Drawable tempDrawable =    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xml_layout);
    LayerDrawable bubble = (LayerDrawable) tempDrawable; //cast to root element in xml
    GradientDrawable solidColor = (GradientDrawable) bubble.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.user_color);
solidColor.setColor(colorToPaint);
    // and then do this 
    linearView.setBackground(tempDrawable);



    // hope this helps you :)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int colorToPaint = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white);// any color you want
Drawable tempDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xml_layout);
LayerDrawable bubble = (LayerDrawable) tempDrawable; //cast to root element in xml
GradientDrawable solidColor = (GradientDrawable) bubble.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.user_color);
solidColor.setColor(colorToPaint);
```

Comment: Where does `imageView` come from?

Comment: I added some vital code to my original question. I'm not using an ImageView.

Comment: I meant, if you wanted to set drawable to ImageView.

Comment: @user5262809
// add id to your linear layout
    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">
// then in code do this :
LinearLayout linearView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

// add anitha's code here
// and then do this 
linearView.setBackground(tempDrawable);



// hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)notesLayout.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative to **Anitha**'s answer would be-

If the `LayerDrawable` is already set to your `ImageView` use below code.

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);
((LayerDrawable)mLinearLayout.getBackground()).findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.user_color).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

This way, if you already have a reference to your `LinearLayout` you do the whole color change in just a single line. And you don't even need to call `setBackground()` for the change to show!

Comment: I am using the shape as my `LinearLayout`'s background. I changed my question to make that clear.

Comment: `getColor()` is deprecated.

Comment: @user5262809 That's very new. Deprecated only from Android 6.0. Use **getColor(R.color.white, null)** instead.