# Change color value programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an XML file in the drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" 
    android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#2A3B5E"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

I would like to change the color value. Is it possible to change the value programmatically?

Comment: You can change the color on the View itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically)!

It retrieves the background containing the drawable shape that you want to modify; otherwise you can instantiate programatically a new  `ShapeDrawable`, assigning all the properties that you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via LevelListDrawable.
Check [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html)