# Create circular looking drawable in android

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable

I want to create a circular color filled drawable with a letter inside it in android java. I want to set the letter and color dynamically. Any ideas how to create it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable
in this repository you can put text in a drawable

Answer (score 0):

Create your TextView like this (this one centers the text):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_circle">
</TextView>
```

Your shape like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/circleColor">
    </solid>
    <size
        android:width="@dimen/circleSize"
        android:height="@dimen/circleSize"
        />
</shape>
```

Then you can set the text in the TextView dynamically as usual with mTextView.setText().

To change the color dynamically, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically).