# Background shape didn't work perfectly in API level 16 in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have designed one shape for applying to the background of my linear layout. it works perfect in API level 21. but didn't work in API level 16.please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
       android:drawable="@android:id/background"
       android:width="3dp"
       android:color="#023e64">
    </stroke>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work in API level 16". WHAT didn't work? What is the outcome and what would you expect?

Answer (score 8):

It is a known bug, that on API 16 the drawable background becomes black.

Just set the background to `android.color.R.transparent`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:drawable="@android:id/background"
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#023e64">
    </stroke>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>


    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: That is not a solution when it comes to change the background color programmatically. Any ideas? or have to give up API16 as bottom target?

Comment: The answer is almost always out there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825210/6507689