# Programmatically change colors in drawable xml file

Tags: android, colors, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I need to change my application's colors during runtime. I parse data file to get colors and I save it in class with static fields and methods:

```
public class Colors {

    private static String colorOneBackground = "#00577F";
    private static String colorOneForeground = "#FFFFFF";

    public static void setColorOneBackground(String colorOneBackground) {
        Colors.colorOneBackground = colorOneBackground;
    }

    public static int getColorOneForeground() {
        return Color.parseColor(colorOneForeground);
    }
    // more colors...
```

Then, for example when I want to change the background of screen I do it so:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.loginBackground);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Colors.getColorOneBackground());
```

Same with textviews and other widgets. However, I have encountered one problem. Some styles are defined in Drawable folder, for example,
mybutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android=" http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android "
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

And I set this as my button's background:

```
<Button  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/title"
   android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />
```

As I said I want to change these color values programatically. So I want to know if it is possible to dinamically change color values defined in xml file?

Comment: Use **setBackGroundRes()** method .

Comment: Please read my question once again. I want to change color values in xml file and I know how to set drawable background in code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically

Comment: In your link the color is being changed using this approach:

GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) background;
    gradientDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToSet));

 but in my xml file I may have different colors for startColor, centerColor and endColor so setColor()  mehod won't work...

Comment: so use `setColors()` method

Comment: Doing the above is unnecessary and just complicates your code..You don't **need** to redefine the colors in xml files.. Just define the different colors used in your application inside the `colors.xml` and use the methods specified in the previous comments to set them.

Answer (score 3):

try this : to change color in your drawable xml file:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybutton);  //drawable id
GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) button.getBackground().getCurrent();
gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); //set color
gd.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"), 5, 6);
```

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem by myself... Anyway, thanks for the help;)

Comment: than post your answer