# How to change Shape solid color programmatically?

Tags: android

How can I change the `<solid android:color= />` programmatically?

I defined a custom shape element:
my_item.xml:

```
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FFFF0000"/>
</shape>
```

And reuse it in another layout: 
grid_view.xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView ... android:src="@drawable/my_item"
                   android:id="@+id/myitemid" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The following does not work:

```
public class ShapeItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
          view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.grid_view, null);
          ImageView shape = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myitemid);
          shape.setBackgroundColor(0xBCCACA); //does not work
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically) before ask ?

Answer (score 5):

I turned out none of the answers provided here have been correct. Important is: use `getDrawable()` on the shape, not `getBackground()`.

```
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) icon.getDrawable();
shape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:-

Get your drawable from resources and change shape color.Then you can set as a background of image view.

```
      GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) mContext.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.todo_list_circle);
    drawable.mutate();
    drawable.setColor(mColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ImageView shape = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myitemid);
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)shape.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: The shape is a `ShapeDrawable`...

Answer (score 0):

Get ShapeDrawable and set color:

```
ImageView shape = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myitemid);
ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) shape.getBackground();
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.my_color));
```

You may wait until layout has been drawn:

```
 ViewTreeObserver to = shape.getViewTreeObserver();
 to.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
     @Override
     public void onGlobalLayout() {
         layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
         ImageView shape = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myitemid);
         ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) shape.getBackground();
         shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.my_color));
     }
 });
```

Comment: `shape.getBackground()` returns `null`. Why don't I have a background?

Comment: I updated my answer @membersound