# How to apply transparency only on background color of buttons

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner on Android Studio and I need your help to apply a specific transparency on my layout.

I applied a background and border color to my layout by using this drawable:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#ffa500" />
</shape>
```

Now I want to apply **dynamically** a transparency to this button (**by using a seek bar**) but only on the background color I don't want to modify my border color.
I tried to use setAlpha function but it also change my border color transparency.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set android shape color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823451/set-android-shape-color-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the alpha portion of the color your specify in  item.

For example - #aarrggbb -- aa part is the alpha.

If you want to change stroke / solid color separately, I recommend using GradientDrawable to `setStroke()` and `setColor()'.

For reference -

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#setColor(int)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setStroke(int,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList,%20float,%20float)

Comment: I forgot to specify that I want to dynamically change the transparency by using a seek bar.

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

In your shape change the  `<solid android:color="@android:color/black" />` to  `<solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />`
This will make your shape transparent.
And in your xml `<Button .... android:background="@drawable/your_shape" />`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to specify that I want to dynamically change the transparency by using a seek bar.

Comment: Ok but if i understand correctly you want to start from transparent? to dynamically change color is controlled from java class. open new question with corresponding problem description.