# How to make a circular drawable with stroke, programmatically?

Tags: android, android-drawable, layerdrawable, android-shapedrawable

### Background

I'm trying to have a filled circle, with a stroke of certain color and width, and an image inside.

This can easily be done in XML, as such (this is just a sample) :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ffff0000"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp" android:color="#ff00ff00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

### The problem

I need to have certain properties of the above to change programmatically, so I can't use the XML file, but the idea is still the same.

Thing is, I can't find an easy way to put a stroke on an OvalShape drawable, as done in XML. I can't find the function to do it.

### What I tried

There are solutions out there here on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find one that works well. Only one I've found is [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3663956/878126), but its stroke line is being cut .

I have, however, partially succeeded in one way to solve this, by using an XML just for the stroke itself:

stroke_drawable.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

code:

```
    final int strokeDrawableResId = R.drawable.stroke_drawable;
    Drawable innerDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), ..., null);
    final Drawable strokeDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), strokeDrawableResId, null);
    ShapeDrawable biggerCircle = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    int size = ...;
    biggerCircle.setIntrinsicHeight(size);
    biggerCircle.setIntrinsicWidth(size);
    biggerCircle.getPaint().setColor(0xffff0000);
    biggerCircle.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, size, size));
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{biggerCircle, strokeDrawable, innerDrawable});

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

It works, but it's not fully programmatically (stroke is defined in XML).

### The question

How to change the code to be fully programmatic ?

---

EDIT: I tried what was suggested here, yet instead of an additional drawable for a background, since I needed it all in one drawable, I used LayerDrawable:

```
    Drawable innerDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), android.R.drawable.btn_star, null);
    int strokeWidth = 5;
    int strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#ff0000ff");
    int fillColor = Color.parseColor("#ffff0000");
    GradientDrawable gD = new GradientDrawable();
    gD.setColor(fillColor);
    gD.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    gD.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{gD, innerDrawable});
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

This works, but for some reason the drawable inside (the star) is being stretched:

[image]

Comment: stroke_drawable.xml won't be required for the answer I've given below.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar I wanted to have a single drawable to set. Background is used for something else (like pressing effect)

Answer (score 17):

You can do this programmatically as 
In `YourActivity.XMl`, Set-up an `ImageView` as usual.

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"                                
            android:padding="15dp"/>
```

And in your `MainActivity.java`

```
    ImageView iV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id1);
    int strokeWidth = 5;
    int strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#03dc13");
    int fillColor = Color.parseColor("#ff0000");
    GradientDrawable gD = new GradientDrawable();
    gD.setColor(fillColor);
    gD.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    gD.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
    iV.setBackground(gD);
```

`setColor` here sets the background color and `setStroke` sets the stroke width and stroke color.
I have created some local variables for color, width etc to make it more easy to understand.
Result
[image]
More you increase the padding, more will the size of circle increase.

Comment: Where's the part that makes it Oval? Why does it have "getBackground" ?

Comment: Can you please show how to do it on Oval shape, and not on a view? Just as the XML shows?

Comment: ImageView can already have a background. I want to create a drawable to set as the content, including what's inside of the circle ("ic_launcher_round" in your case) , just as I've shown on the question. It's the circle, the outline, and the content together. I want to have them all inside one drawable that's not in XML. You've put a part of it in XML. However, I think this can be fixed with LayerDrawable, no?

Comment: I want to have the same content as I've shown on the drawable XML that I've shown, yet programmatically. The drawable should contain all as the XML has. However, I think this can be done using LayerDrawable. I think your solution could work if it had it instead of "src" being set in XML.

Comment: I tried the LayerDrawable I wrote, but it gets stretched. Updated question to hold this solution

Comment: Again, I need to use a single drawable, as a full conversion of what I had in XML.